# Formas dos pronomes oblíquos conforme as terminações dos verbos

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos

Por que pronomes oblíquos mudam a sua forma conforme a terminação verbal ?

Claro que experimentar usar apenas uma forma, suponha a forma "o(s) e a(s)", soa estranho uma vez acostumado com as demais formas em cada um dos respectivos casos. Mas continuaria a ser estranho ou haveria algum prejuízo na comunicação ou escrita se fosse apenas uma forma ? Há algum prejuízo fonético ?

Regras das formas:

- Terminado com som nasal (ão, m, ...): **no(s), na(s)**
- Terminado com r, s e z: **lo(s), la(s)**
- Demais: **o(s), a(s)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O pronome objeto clítico (ou pronome oblíquo átono) da terceira pessoa é alomorfo (isto é, é um morfema com várias representações fonéticas) por dois motivos:

- Porque esses pronomes são clíticos;
- E porque a língua portuguesa passou por certas alterações fonéticas durante sua evolução.

### Clíticos

Um clítico é uma palavra que é morfologicamente independente, porém foneticamente ligada a outra palavra. Por exemplo, a expressão *"amá-la"* contém, morfologicamente, duas palavras (*amar* e *la*), mas contém foneticamente apenas uma ("*amála*").

Isso é notável em outras línguas de origem latina, onde o verbo e o pronome objeto são de fato escritos como uma única palavra sem hifenização (sem serem separados por hífen). Essa mesma expressão *"amá-la"*, em espanhol e italiano é *["amarla"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amarla)*.

### Lenição intervocálica

A lenição intervocálica foi uma alteração fonética que ocorreu nos contextos /ala, ela, elo .../ ou qualquer combinação de duas vogais separadas por "L" (exceto quando essas vogais forem ao mesmo tempo `/u/` ou `/i/`).

Nesses contextos, a consoante `/l/` foi eliminada, e as duas vogais, que antes eram separadas pela consoante, passaram a ser unidas. Veja alguns exemplos (do latim vulgar ibérico para o português antigo e para o português moderno):

- "palo" > "pao" > "pau"
- "polo" > "poo" > "pó"
- "volar" > "voar"

Essa lenição atingiu as palavras formadas por verbo+pronome clítico (pois, como disse, verbos e pronomes clíticos formam, fonologicamente, uma palavra só).

Veja, por exemplo, a expressão *"ame-a"* (em espanhol *"ámela"*), que, no latim vulgar tardio, era, assim como no espanhol, *"ámela"* (ame+la). Devido à lenição intervocálica, o *"ámela"* perdeu o "L" e virou *"ámea"* (ou *"ame-a"*, já que a ortografia moderna separa pronomes clíticos por hífen).

### Assimilação lateral e degeminação

A [assimilação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)) lateral foi uma alteração fonética que ocorreu em /arla, esla, izlo, .../ e qualquer combinação de duas vogais separadas por "RL, SL, ZL".

Nesses contextos, o som `/rl/` transformou-se em `/ll/` devido à [assimilação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)), ou seja, o "R" assimilou-se em "L". Não conheço muitos exemplos de assimilação, mas um bem famoso é o da palavra latina vulgar "perlo", formado pela união da preposição "per" e do pronome "lo", que tornou-se a palavra "pello" por assimilação.

A consoante geminada (ou dupla) `/ll/` não sofreu lenição (diferente da forma simples não geminada `/l/`, que tratei na seção anterior), porém foi degeminada (isto é, os dois "L"-s combinaram-se num só `/l/`). Veja alguns exemplos:

- "elle" > "ele"
- "collo" > "colo"
- "bolla" > "bola"
- "bella" > "bela"
- "perla" > "pella" > "pela" (assimilação seguida de degeminação `/rl > ll > l/`

No caso dos pronomes clíticos aconteceu a assimilação seguida de degeminação. Por exemplo, a expressão *"amá-la"* (em espanhol *"amarla"*), que, no latim vulgar, era *"amarla"* (amar+la). Devido à assimilação, o *"amárla"* virou  *"amálla"*, que virou *"amála"* pela degeminação. E como a ortografia portuguesa separa pronomes clíticos por hífen, hoje temos *"amá-la"*.

### O caso nasal

No caso de flexões verbais terminadas em som nasal, não consegui encontrar fontes fiáveis explicando o caso específico do desenvolvimento de "amenla" para "amem-na". Mas vou deixar aqui minhas opiniões das causas possíveis (editarei essa resposta quando achar algo relevante, mas essas duas opções são bastante plausíveis dado o sistema evolutivo do português):

- Pode ter sido a lenição intervocálica do /-l-/ seguido da fortição do /-n-/.
  (ou seja: `/amenla > amẽa > amena/`).
- Ou a assimilação de `/-nl-/` em `/nn/` seguido da degeminação.
  (ou seja: `/amenla > amenna > amena/`).

### Resumindo

**-o(as):**
"*Ame-la > ame-a*" (`/'a.me.la > 'a.me.a/`), pela lenição intervocálica. Compare com o espanhol "ámela", que não sofreu lenição.

**-lo(as):**

"*Amar-la > amal-la > amá-la*" (`/a'mar.la > a'mal.la > a'ma.la/`), pela assimilação do "R" em "L", seguida pela degeminação dessa consoante. Compare com o espanhol e italiano "amarla", que não sofreu assimilação (e, consequentemente, nem degeminação).

**-no(as), evolução 1:**

*"Amen-la > amen-a > amem-na"* (`/'a.men.la > 'a.mẽ.a > 'a.mẽ.na/`), pela lenição do "L", seguida pela fortição do "N".
Compare com o espanhol "ámenla".

**-no(as), evolução 2:**

*"Amen-la > amen-na > amem-na"* (`/'a.men.la > 'a.mẽn.na > 'a.mẽ.na/`), pela assimilação do "L" em "N", seguida pela degeminação dessa consoante. Compare com o espanhol "ámenla".

Eu não sei porque a ortografia portuguesa separa o pronome clítico do verbo por hífen, enquanto que na ortografia do espanhol e do italiano isso não ocorre. Não entendo muito da evolução ortográfica (mas creio que essa dúvida valha uma outra pergunta aqui no site).

O livro [Portuguese: A linguistic Introduction](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=tWk6gpv8ep0C), que uso como referência, explica a evolução fonética do português, porém apenas cita, sem discutir, o caso do clítico nasal.

### Terminologia

**Lenição:** Alteração fonética em que um som se enfraquece, fazendo com que, dentre outras coisas, consoantes desapareçam ou tornem-se vogais ou características suprafonéticas (como a nasalização).

**Fortição:** Alteração fonética em que um som se fortalece, fazendo com que, dentre outras coisas, características suprafonéticas (como a nasalização) ou vogais tornem-se consoantes.

**Assimilação:** Alteração fonética em que um som torna-se parecido ou igual a um som adjacente.

**Geminação:** Alteração fonética em que uma consoante torna-se geminada, ou dupla/longa. O latim possuía consoantes geminadas, mas o português não possui. Porém há reflexos da geminação latina no português, como em "assa" vs. "asa"; "morro" vs. "moro"; "-ão" vs. "ano" etc.

**Degeminação:** Alteração fonética em que uma consoante geminada torna-se simples. Todas as consoantes geminadas do latim foram degeminadas no português.

**Clítico:** Palavra que é morfologicamente independente mas é fonologicamente parte de uma palavra maior, com a qual é pronunciada e sofre as evoluções fonéticas como se fossem uma única palavra.

**Alomorfia:** Condição em que um morfema possui mais de uma realização fonética. Cada realização é chamada de alomorfo (por exemplo, "-o, -no, -lo" são três alomorfos de um mesmo morfema).

Comment: Muito interessante. Eu já vi em textos antigos *ena, eno* por *na, no*. Creio que isto seria um exemplo da possibilidade "amẽa > amena" que avançaste, não? "Em a" : /ẽ a/ > /na/

Comment: Foi nas Cantigas de Santa Maria, sXIII: [Ena Gran Bretanna foi hũa sazon](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tuPLowwEmIgC&pg=PA315&dq=%22Ena+Gran+Bretanna+foi%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH4sTSqK_WAhXF1RoKHb77D2wQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Ena%20Gran%20Bretanna%20foi%22&f=false)

Comment: @Jacinto. Isso pode ter sido também a assimilação de L com N, na contração da preposição **en** com o proto-artigo **la** (`/enla > enna > ena > na/`). Da mesma forma que a contração **pela** veio da assimilação de **per** com o proto-artigo **la** (`/perla > pella > pela/`)". O que você propõe é que a contração "na" viria da preposição moderna **ẽ** com o artigo também moderno **a** (`/ẽa > ena > na/`). Mas não creio que seja esse o caso, imagino que ambas as contrações se desenvolveram simultaneamente antes, durante a "pré-história" da língua português (quando **a** ainda era **la**).

Comment: Ainda assim, não imagino o que teria ocasionado a deleção do /e/ em /ena > na/. Mas a vogal deletada já era curta e também foi deletada nas contrações das outras línguas (vide o italiano "nel < in+il").

Comment: Sim, é verdade. Modernamente, sXIX, encontramos também coisas com [*não na faz*](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22n%C3%A3o+na+faz%22&oq=%22n%C3%A3o+na+faz%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...227500.229103.0.229806.4.3.1.0.0.0.163.310.2j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.7pDSMEvymVA) por *não a faz*. Ou isto já vem do protoportuguês ou então só mesmo por fortição, não?

Answer (score 1):

Os pronomes eram originalmente lo, la, los e las, mas o L deixou de se pronunciar entre duas vogais.

Nas formas que terminavam em r, s e z, havia assimilação destas consoantes ao l do pronome.

Por outro lado, as que terminavam em som nasal, era o o l do pronome que assimilava num n.

[Fonte.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-origem-de--lo-e--no-pronome-pessoal--o/34400)